# Получить blob ячейку из БД wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Каким способом в wordpress получить из БД ячейку BLOB?
При помощи кода ниже удаётся только получить INT ячейки.
Когда запрос идёт на BLOB ячейку, то возвращается пустой массив (в мануалах пишут, что это из-за того, что строк по запросу не найдено или ошибка запроса. Строка найдена, так как если в запросе получить int ячейку, она возвращается, а ошибок никаких не видно).

```
$columnOrder = $wpdb->get_results ( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT Order FROM Orders WHERE ID_Account = $cur_user_id AND ID_Top = %d AND ID_Server = %d AND ID_SubServer = %d", $ID_Top, $ID_Server, $ID_SubServer
        )
    );
```

Comment: Не надо спамить вопросами. Вы удалили старый, и задали новый, с целью перетащить его наверх. Такое поведение совсем не приветствуется. Если вам не отвечают - это значит, что ваш вопрос или неинтересен, или на него нет времени у тех, кто мог бы ответить.

Comment: @KAGGDesign хорошо, в будущем учту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка оказалась банальной донельзя. В запросе я ссылался на ячейку `Order`, а данное имя ячейки использовать нельзя. Поэтому и была ошибка